# how to rename the file name based on the existing file names

Tags: excel, vba

I have filenames in the format of File-2-Mar-17, File-10-Apr-17 and so on.

Is there a way where when I click save command button, the workbook I am on gets saved as File-Mar or File-Apr? Here, I’ll only be selecting files corresponding to the similar month.

Secondly when I have files like File-Jan, File-Feb, File-Mar and I reconcile them (another macro runs here), when I click the save button could I have the file saved as File-Jan_Feb_Mar or File-Oct_Nov_Dec?

I do know the standard SaveAs procedure. But in this case since I am using `Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)` to select multiple files, I am at a loss on how it has to be performed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for,

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="D:\" & Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 3, 3)
```

Please let me know if i am wrong. i will try to resolve your issue